# Getting wxPython with Ubuntu 16.04 and using it with Pycharm

Tags: python, ubuntu, wxpython, pycharm

I'm trying to make a window with wxPython, but trying to install it into the project interpreter in my Pycharm project doesn't work. I then tried installing it onto my computer, but that didn't work either. I've read that wxPython is not very compatible with Linux, so I'm drawing a blank. How do I get wxPython onto Ubuntu 16.04 and then allow me to use Pycharm in order to make the window?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Also, listing whatever error you get when you try to install would useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an old version of wxPython using apt-get. Something like this should work:

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk3.0
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8
```

But if you want the latest wxPython, you can use pip:

```
pip install wxPython
```

I highly recommend installing the latest version, which is **wxPython 4**.

Comment: For getting wxPython4 with pip for some specific Linux distros see https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/ For building yourself for other Linux distros see https://wxpython.org/blog/2017-08-17-builds-for-linux-with-pip/index.html and the project README.

Answer (score 0):

Add the repository and update package list

```
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main universe" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wily-copies.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-wxgtk2.8
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wily-copies.list
sudo apt update
```

done...
working on Raspberry pi also.